# Asymptotic complexity of power of logs

Tags: logarithms, asymptotics, computational-complexity

I'm trying to simplify $\Theta(lg^k(n/2))$.

I believe it's $\Theta(lg^kn)$ but i don't know if the following proof is correct... i'd love to receive some input

I tried doing -

$$\Theta(lg^k(n/2))=\Theta(lg(n/2)*lg(n/2)*lg(n/2)*...*lg(n/2))=\Theta((lg\,n-lg\,2)*(lg\,n-lg\,2)*(lg\,n-lg\,2)*...*(lg\,n-lg\,2))=\Theta(\Theta(lg\,n)^k)=\Theta(lg^kn)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upper O-bound is trivial.

To establish the lower bound,

consider the following limit and apply L Hospital rule repeatedly
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\lg^{k}2x}{\lg^{k}x}$$

Note that
$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\lg2x\right) =\dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\lg x\right)$$

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed a solution and if no other solutions will be given, i'll mark it as the answer. But what i really am after is knowing if my solution is fault or not...

Comment: Indeed, the $\Theta$ notation is not an operator.
Therefore, $\Theta(\Theta(f))$ does not make sense at all